# Injectivity means $a_1 = a_2 \Longleftrightarrow f(a_1) = f(a_2)$? Structuring Proof of Injectivity.

Tags: functions, proof-verification

> Let $f$ be a function from $A$ to $B$ and $g$ a function from $B$ to $C$. Show that if the composite function $g \circ f$ is one–to–one (injective), then $f$ is one–to–one (injective).

My understanding is that, for infectivity, we have to prove both

1. If $a_1 = a_2$, then $f(a_1) = f(a_2)$, and
2. If $f(a_1) = f(a_2)$, then $a_1 = a_2$.

My proof was going to go something like this.

**Proof**

Suppose $g \circ f$ is injective (one-to-one), where $f: A \to B$ and $g: B \to C$.

(Part 1) Let $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, where $x_1, x_2 \in A$.

Therefore, $g(f(x_1)) = g(f(x_2))$. But since $g \circ f$ is injective, each element in the image of $g \circ f$ is mapped to by only one element in the domain of $g \circ f$.

Therefore, we must have that $x_1 = x_2$.

I was then going to do part 2, which would instead assume that $x_1 = x_2$, where $x_1 = x_2 \in A$. But the proof that I saw online did not do this part; instead, they only did part 1 and said that the proof is complete. Wouldn't we have to do both parts, since it is a logical equivalence (injectivity means $a_1 = a_2 \Longleftrightarrow f(a_1) = f(a_2)$)?

And if so, can someone please demonstrate the second part?

Comment: for injectivity you need to show #2, not #1. #1 is for well-definedness.

Comment: @AnuragA Oh? So injectivity is $f(a_1) = f(a_2) \Longrightarrow a_1 = a_2$ only? Not $a_1 = a_2 \Longleftrightarrow f(a_1) = f(a_2)$?

Comment: yes that's correct.

Comment: @AnuragA Oh, ok. Thank you for that. Can you then please also specify what subjectivity would be, in the same way? Just so I'm sure I don't get confused with that one too.

Comment: surjectivity or onto means, for each $y \in B$, there exists an $x \in A$ such that $f(x)=y$. Basically for every element in set $B$, there is something in $A$ that maps to it.

Comment: @AnuragA So, writing in the same way as above, it means $y \in B \Longrightarrow f(x) = y$? Not $y \in B \Longleftrightarrow f(x) = y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $r,t \in A$. Suppose $f(r)=f(t)$, then $g(f(r))=g(f(t))$. But $g \circ f$ is injective implies $r=t$. Thus $f$ is injective.